# Create taxonomy terms on the fly

Tags: taxonomy-terms

As far as I know, the way to create a taxonomy term is having to go into the taxonomy module and creating on there, and THEN assigning the term to the node.

Is there a way to create taxonomy terms on the fly? When the node is created, if the taxonomy term doesn't exist, it should be created too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module:

> Hierarchical Select has the ability to save the entire lineage of a
>   selection or only the "deepest" selection. You can configure it to
>   force the user to make a selection as deep as possible in the tree, or
>   allow the user to select an item anywhere in the tree. Levels can be
>   labeled, you can configure limit the number of items that can be
>   selected, configure a title for the dropbox, choose a site-wide
>   animation delay, and so on. **You can even create new items and levels
>   through Hierarchical Select!**

Another way is selecting *Autocomplete term widget (tagging)* as field widget, when creating your term reference field

As another option, there is the [Simple hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) module.

Comment: I always thought Autocomplete was solely for searching already created terms. Thanks for telling me about it.

Answer (score 2):

```
 //see if this term already exists and fetch it if it does
  $term = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($i);

  //if it doesn't exist, make it
  if ($term == array()){
    //make a new class to hold the term for taxonomy 1
    $taxonomy = new stdClass();
    $taxonomy->name = $i;
    // mentioned vid here as of now i placed 1.
    $taxonomy->vid = 1;
    taxonomy_term_save($taxonomy);
    //now fetch it so we have it's tid
    $term = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($i);
  }

  //set $tid as it's returned from  taxonomy_get_term_by_name
  $tid = key($term);

  //tag the node with the appropriate tag
   $node->field_tags['und'][0] = array('tid' => $tid);

  //save the tagged node
  node_save($node);
  $i++;
```

Above code will check for term exist and if not creates new term, when creating new content.

Comment: This little snippet of code has help me oh so many times, that I just want to say thank you for sharing it.

Comment: Just to note here.. The the vid is not the version id as used for revisions, but its the Vocabulary ID. If you don't want to use the VID you can use $tazonomy->vocabulary_machine_name

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above suggestions, once can go for autocomplete_delux(https://www.drupal.org/project/autocomplete_deluxe) and entity_autocreate(https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_autocreate) modules.

These behave in manner just as the above modules; plus they fall under Drupal Security Policy

Answer (score -2):

I'd like to suggest the [Manage Multiple Terms](https://drupal.org/project/manage_multiple_terms) module:

> Manage Multiple Terms provides a simple mechanism to add, update,
>   delete many terms in the same time easily and quickly.