# How to save a new term with multiple fields while adding content?

Tags: 7, nodes, taxonomy-terms, entities

Not only do I want to [add terms as I create content](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/18507/39617) through the UI, but I want to add terms that have multiple fields (i.e. more fields on the taxonomy besides the 'Name' that populates the list). How can this be done?

I'm mixing a few concepts here:

1. Add terms through the Add/Edit Content page
2. Display the different fields of a taxonomy on the Add/Edit Content page.

Comment: You need to supply more details on what you want. Do you mean programatically, or do you intend to have a UI for an end user? The answer is either `field_attach_load` and use the typical field API to save the related fields on save(). Or, to look at like the References Dialog module to allow you to create a new term from a popup window, which will allow completion of the non-typical terms.

Comment: References Dialog may not work with taxonomy term references now, but there are similar modules in that UX space ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [References dialog](https://www.drupal.org/project/references_dialog) module with [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1429288#comment-7060628) patch

> This module extends reference fields like the user and node reference fields by adding links to add, edit and search for references through a dialog. This allows for a workflow where the user can create all the references to a node at the same time as she is creating it, a process which sometimes get's a bit backwards, when a user for instance needs to create all the facts for an article.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fieldset [field set](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection_fieldset) module to create multiple fields with in a single field.