# Create new taxonomy terms on the fly and assign an icon for each one

Tags: taxonomy-terms, media

This is in extend of this question: [Create taxonomy terms on the fly](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18507/create-taxonomy-terms-on-the-fly)

I would like to assign icons for news categories:

The editor should be able to create a news article, assign one or more new categories to it (taxonomy terms in News-tags vocabulary) and be able to upload an icon for each one of them.

The first part has been answered in Mechaflash's question, but I'm having a hard time implementing the icon requirement.

I've already created an Image field for the vocabulary items. I can create terms and assign images/icons to them. The problem is I can't find a way to display it on the new content creation form, so the editor can add them on the fly.

Is this possible somehow?