# Create taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 9

i'm new to drupal (just installed v9) and want to add a bunch of content.
like in the question asked years ago ([Create taxonomy terms on the fly](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18507/create-taxonomy-terms-on-the-fly)) i want to add taxonomy terms on the fly while adding new content and not having to add them first in the taxonomy module.

the links provided in the old thread are for v7 and v8 and seem not to work

if the code thats posted there is still a valid solution can one tell me where to add it?
thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create taxonomy terms on the fly](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18507/create-taxonomy-terms-on-the-fly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always there is more than one way of doing things in Drupal.

I'll guess that one of the popular ways of solving this problem currently is with the [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) module.

Once you have it installed you can go to the "Manage form display" of your Content type and choose the Inline entity form Simple or Complex for your Taxonomy ER field (Complex allows you to also add existing entities, not only create new ones on the fly). Adjust the settings to your needs.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i added the version ment for v8 and then checked the box and installed it (got a checked grey checkbox now). at "manage form display" i tried to find the mentioned "simple" and "complex" option for the field in the dropdown menu under the row "structure element/widget" but cant find it. i can only select "autocomplete (tags - style), checkbox, autocomplete and selection list".

Comment: Have you tried clearing entire cache and then visiting the Manage form display? Those options should appear on ER fields, although I haven't tried it straight on 9.

Comment: Wow, its working and better then i thought. 
My second question would've been how to "inline" add content pages but yeah this module does it all! Thanks you so much! :)

Comment: Content items and Taxonomy items are all entity items, so it works exactly the same for nodes. Create an Entity Reference field that references (a) Content Type(s) instead of Taxonomy and set that form to use Inline Entity Form widget.